# How to get comma separated data from 1 table and get related data from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 1 table in which category are stored.
e.g:

```
CategoryId      CategoryName
-------------------------------
1              General

2              dummy

3              test
```

now i have 1 another table in which i store the articles and in that table i store articles id with comma separated values,as 1 article can be in more than 1 category

```
ArticleID       Content       CategoryId
-------------------------------------------
1              Test            1,2
2              Test2           1,3
3              Test3           1,2,3
4              Test4           2
```

Now at front side when i display the article i want to display article categoryname also.

So can you tell me how can i achieve this???

Output should be like::

```
ArticleId      Content        Category
------------------------------------------
1             Test             General,dummy
2             Test2            General,test
3             Test3            General,dummy,test
4             Test4            dummy
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should consider changing your data model.

Create an extra table Article_Category (ArticleID, CategoryID), and for each article put in a row for each category the article belongs to.

The query then becomes a simple join of the three tables. Sort the output by article and category, and you can easily "flatten" the output in the GUI.

Comment: Agreed, Kishan would spend far less time doing a better data model and a one time data conversion than building complicated string tokenizer(s) and unclear queries to get the results he is looking for.

Comment: @Suirtimed, I am developing website which is goinf to generated lots of records( lacks, thousands) so i have to maintain database very clean and in normalized form.and i have to make website speed very fast so for that this things are important ..

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do this with the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function. I don't think there is something like this in T-SQL, but you could use it in your search. Here is an example of someone asking about it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/f09d4166-2030-41fe-b86e-392fbc94db53.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

*If* you know some .NET you can create something like a StringAggregator. You're previous questions indicate you do know some programming.

Create a SQL Server 2005/2008 project and use this code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO

<Serializable()> _
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined, MaxByteSize:=8000)> _
Public Structure StringAggrComma
    Implements IBinarySerialize

    Private values As List(Of String)

    Public Sub Init()
        ' Put your code here
        values = New List(Of String)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Accumulate(ByVal value As SqlString)
        ' Put your code here
        values.Add(value.Value.Trim)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Merge(ByVal value As StringAggrComma)
        ' Put your code here
        For Each val As String In value.values
            Accumulate(val)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function Terminate() As SqlString
        ' Put your code here
        Return New SqlString(String.Join(", ", values.ToArray))
    End Function

    Public Sub Write(ByVal w As System.IO.BinaryWriter) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.IBinarySerialize.Write
        w.Write(values.Count)
        For Each item As String In values
            w.Write(item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub Read(ByVal r As System.IO.BinaryReader) Implements Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.IBinarySerialize.Read
        values = New List(Of String)
        For i As Int32 = 0 To r.ReadInt32
            values.Add(r.ReadString)
        Next
    End Sub
End Structure
```